# Is there an upper limit for users in WP?

Tags: users, scale

Right now I use a single WP table to feed several sites.  We have about 72K users and I have started noticing that to see the "Users" page it takes about 30 seconds on our otherwise pretty fast server.  Are there any scalability issues I should worry about and anything I can do to get the user functions working quicker?

Extra Info:  The user table is added to each night using employee data.  There is nothing writing to the user table.  We do allow users to edit some extra fields that get put into the metauser table.  However there is no sign-up or registration.  All of the sites simply define the user/meta tables in the config.

Comment: It's probably a simple DB optimisation problem: the WordPress team might not test with anything that big. You could try running a MySQL profiler against your database to see exactly what query the page is running and whether it's having to do full table scans to get there, or separate queries per user, or something else crazy.

Comment: can you explain a little more? why are your different site use the same table and do all of them right to it?

Comment: @Rup - Not sure about that.  When I query the users in my database it is very fast.  When pulling up the user page it is very slow.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - Added more stuff.  Does that clear it up?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with 72,000 users being there. I think it has to do with the ~72,000 * 20 (1,440,000) entries in the wp_usermeta table that will be queried in various fashions to determine permissions and display data.

Comment: @BA_Webimax - my users are pulling up info fast on profiles and stuff.  Right now it is only the admin User page that I have noticed being an issue.

Comment: Try throwing BlackBox Debug Bar (https://wordpress.org/plugins/blackbox-debug-bar/) in and look at the profiling and SQL queries being run. This might provide some insight as to why that page is so slow.

Answer (score 3):

For every scaling question you can look at wordpress.com and see how big they are. I do't know the details but I think that with all the users of wordpress.com itself, akismet users and jetpack users, an estimate of 1M users can't be totally wrong.. In addition so far as far as auttomatic people say they are running vanilla wordpress (or very very close to it) with plugins.

So can it scale scale above 100k users? seems like the answer is an easy yes. So how much time does it take them to load the users page? I think the answer is that wordpress do not have the tools to easily admin this amount of info and just because of UX reasons you will never want to go to the users page when you have so many users.

So maybe there are two separate questions here, Can wordpress scale to have 100k user? yes! Does vanilla wordpress give you the tools to easily admin so many users? probably not.

Comment: It really seems like a flaw in code for the Users page.  I have a massive table I use - my own code - for all 72K plus 60 employee fields.  It does take a while to load the first page but that is 7-9 seconds not 90 seconds.  The disappointing thing is when I search for a username it takes a good minute to get back.

Comment: hmm, a user can login instantly but searching for the user name takes a minute? It doesn't really add up. You should take a look at what is exactly the query when you do it.

Comment: I am just using the search on the User page.  If I do a search directly on database it takes 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Have/can you turn on [SAVEQUERIES](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#SAVEQUERIES) to see what query/ies are causing the delay?

Comment: a search for a word in 72K entries can be fast or slow depending on how you search ..... If your search has to compare all the rows to a string then it will be slow. As I said above, the user admin is not built to handle so much data and if you really need to admin the users out of wordpress (I fail to actually see why if you import the table from external source) then you will need to develop tools or figure out methods to handle your specific needs.

Answer (score -2):

Simply put, the only limitation is the size of your web server and database. RAM is an issue as well. If you're using a server without a lot of ram and running all of that then Ram could be the issue. I hope you figure it out.

Comment: RAM is not a limitation as you don't have to store the user data in memory. The amount of RAM you have is important for the responsiveness of the site, not the size of data it can hold. Even disk space is not an issue as you can hold fragments of your DB on as many servers as you like and add more servers if you need more storage.